# Access User context from a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, class

**Background:**

- I have a win app and a web app and a
  shared class library.
- In my class lib I have some static
  methods for SQL queries which pick up
  my SQL connection string
- I store my SQL connection string in a
  Session variable since it is set at
  log in time where it is determined
  which database to use.
- My class lib cannot access my session
  variables (yes, of course I can use
  HttpContext.Current..., but that wont
  work in my winapp)

**Solution?**

I envision a sort of solution where I have a class for my current user/context and when creating it I inject the preferred behaviour, something like this:

```
UserContex current = new UserContext();
current.SessionHandler = new AspNetSessionHandler();
```

However, I would like a static class which I could user without having to pass it along all the time and then it would get it's variables either from the session if used in a web app or from somewhere else (I'm not a winapp developer) if used in a winform.

I will try to conjure up this kind of thing, but it would be great if I found an already working solution and that's why I call on the shared collective madness of you guys

Comment: Hi Mr W

I am facing the same issue, may i know how did you solve it

Answer (score 1):

Csla contains a similar setup using a static ApplicationContext class which is discussed in Rockford Lhotka's book Expert C# Business Objects...To deal with the connection string issue I would suggest creating a DataConnection class that returns a static connection string from the config file that way it doesn't matter if the connection string is coming from the Web.config or the App.config

```
public class DataConnection
{


    public static string NameOfConnection
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfConnection"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's the thing. I need to read the connection string from my Session variables since it varies depending on who is logging in.

Comment: You could move the logic that determines the connection string for the user into the DataConnection class that way it would work for both win app and web app